# Unsupervised anomaly detection - metric for tuning Isolation Forest parameters

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, hyperparameter, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I have a project, in which, one of the stages is to find and label anomalous data points, that are likely to be outliers.

As a first step, I am using Isolation Forest algorithm, which, after plotting and examining the normal-abnormal data points, works pretty well. 
To somehow measure the performance of IF on the dataset, its results will be compared to the domain knowledge rules. Kind of heuristics where we have a set of rules and we recognize the data points conforming to the rules as normal.

My task now is to make the Isolation Forest perform as good as possible. To do this, I want to use `GridSearchCV` to find the most optimal parameters, but I need to find a proper metric to measure IF performance.
However, my data set is unlabelled and the domain knowledge IS NOT to be seen as the 'correct' answer. So I cannot use the domain knowledge as a benchmark.

What I know is that the features' values for normal data points should not be spread much, so I came up with the idea to minimize the range of the features among 'normal' data points. I want to calculate the range for each feature for each `GridSearchCV` iteration and then sum the total range. The minimal range sum will be (probably) the indicator of the best performance of IF.

The problem is that the features take values that vary in a couple of orders of magnitude. Some have range (0,100), some (0,1 000) and some as big a (0,100 000) or (0,1 000 000). To overcome this I thought of 2 solutions:

1. Scale all features' ranges to the interval [-1,1] or [0,1]. However, the difference in the order of magnitude seems not to be resolved (?)
2. After all iterations of `GridSearchCV` scale EACH feature range INDIVIDUALLY to the interval [0,1] and then sum features' ranges. The iteration with minimal sum should indicate the best IF performance. This method seems robust to different orders of magnitude of the features.

Is there maybe a better metric that can be used for unlabelled data and unsupervised learning to hypertune the parameters? Does my idea no. 2 seems reasonable or I am missing something?

I will be grateful for any hints or points flaws in my reasoning.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same situation, I have data not labelled and I want to detect the outlier, did you find a way to do that, or did you change the model?

Comment: I used the Isolation Forest, but this required a vast amount of expertise and tuning. It is a hard to solve problem, so cannot really point to any specific direction not knowing the data and your domain.